# Why does 8 bit .png exported cycles render shows as 32bit in properties?

Tags: rendering, export

I'm working on some renders and try to minimize file size. Since I need alpha channels, I'm using PNG. I always save the render as 8bit with 15% compression. but after when I check the properties in windows it shows as 32bit. then after I import it into photoshop it's again as 8bit and I can't lower it anymore.
What is the best way to keep alpha and minimize file size? (about 10 to 20% quality loss is ok)

Comment: 8 bits _per channel_ x 4 channels _per pixel_ (RGBA) = 32 bits _per pixel_. Windows is telling you about the pixel while Blender and Photoshop are telling you about the channel.

Comment: Oh thank you soo much!